# Alter table in loop to add multiple fields vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use the alter table command to add fields to an existing table, with code restated below. However I get an error on the first db.execute command saying "too many fields defined". This code should create around (12+4)*3=48 new columns. The values from the form are as follows (just in case):

1. me.yearsback= 1
2. me.valdate = 5/31/2016
3. me.period = "monthly"

Need some help here. Is there a different command I should be using or a totally different approach?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub EP_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim Months As Integer
Dim WPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly written premium
Dim UPRmonthly As String ' field name for monthly unearned premium
Dim EPmonthly As String ' field name for monthly earned premium
Dim runningDate As Date
Dim runningDate2 As Date
Dim useDateLower As Date
Dim useDateUpper As Date

Months = Me.YearsBack * 12 + Month(Me.ValDate)

If Me.Period = "monthly" Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For x = 1 To Months
    runningDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 1, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
    WPmonthly = "WP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
    EPmonthly = "EP M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
    UPRmonthly = "UPR M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
    db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & WPmonthly & "] STRING;"
    db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & EPmonthly & "] STRING;"
    db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & UPRmonthly & "] STRING;"
    If x = Months Then
        runningDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -x + 1, Me.ValDate), "mm yyyy")
        UPRmonthly = "UPR M" & Month(runningDate) & " " & Year(runningDate)
        db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblEPdata ADD COLUMN [" & UPRmonthly & "] STRING;"
    End If



        Next
   End If
        db.Close

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an Access bug where it thinks you have exceeded the 255 column limit. Try:

> In Microsoft Access 7.0 or 97, click Save As/Export on the File menu
>   and save the table under a different name. Then, delete the original
>   table and rename to new table to the original table name.
>
> WARNING: Clicking Save As on the File menu in version 1.x or 2.0
>   copies only the structure of a table, not the records. Do not delete
>   the original table until you use an append query to populate the new
>   table.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/128221

Answer (score 0):

For each field you are going to add instead of alter table use:

```
db.TableDefs("Your Table").CreateField(your variable,dbtext)
```